# Get country name from Country code in python?

Tags: python, phone-number

I have worked with 2 python libraries: [phonenumbers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phonenumbers), [pycountry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry). I actually could not find a way to give just country code and get its corresponding country name.

In `phonenumbers` you need to provide full numbers to `parse`. In `pycountry` it just get country ISO.

Is there a solution or a method in any way to give the library country code and get country name?

Comment: Presumably when you say country code, you mean International Calling Codes. Is this true, or do you actually mean ISO 3166-1 alpha-2?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have a look at `phonenumberutils.region_codes_for_country_code`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `phonenumbers` library is rather under-documented; instead they advice you to look at the original Google project for unittests to learn about functionality.

The [`PhoneNumberUtilTest` unittests](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/master/java/libphonenumber/test/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtilTest.java) seems to cover your specific use-case; mapping the country portion of a phone number to a given region, using the [`getRegionCodeForCountryCode()` function](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/1d4da3c7e7553a320e3ab8741c732273d94db62f/java/libphonenumber/test/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtilTest.java#L1292-L1298). There is also a [`getRegionCodeForNumber()` function](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/1d4da3c7e7553a320e3ab8741c732273d94db62f/java/libphonenumber/test/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtilTest.java#L1300-L1306) that appears to extract the country code attribute of a parsed number first.

And indeed, there are corresponding [`phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.region_code_for_country_code()`](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/blob/2ce2a027bf3c26a95dc233d941483ec34b232506/python/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.py#L2068-L2083) and [`phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.region_code_for_number()`](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/blob/2ce2a027bf3c26a95dc233d941483ec34b232506/python/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.py#L2022-L2044) functions to do the same in Python:

```
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers.phonenumberutil import (
    region_code_for_country_code,
    region_code_for_number,
)

pn = phonenumbers.parse('+442083661177')
print(region_code_for_country_code(pn.country_code))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import phonenumbers
>>> from phonenumbers.phonenumberutil import region_code_for_country_code
>>> from phonenumbers.phonenumberutil import region_code_for_number
>>> pn = phonenumbers.parse('+442083661177')
>>> print(region_code_for_country_code(pn.country_code))
GB
>>> print(region_code_for_number(pn))
GB
```

The resulting region code is a 2-letter ISO code, so you can use that directly in `pycountry`:

```
>>> import pycountry
>>> country = pycountry.countries.get(alpha_2=region_code_for_number(pn))
>>> print(country.name)
United Kingdom
```

Note that the `.country_code` attribute is *just an integer*, so you can use `phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.region_code_for_country_code()` without a phone number, just a country code:

```
>>> region_code_for_country_code(1)
'US'
>>> region_code_for_country_code(44)
'GB'
```

Comment: Note that this won't be able to distinguish between a number being in Canada or US, since they have the same country code.

Comment: For this there is: phonenumbers.geocoder.country_name_for_number(n, "en") == "Canada"

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why nobody has written about [phone-iso3166](https://pypi.org/project/phone-iso3166/?ref=hackernoon.com) so far, but actually this does the work:

```
>>> from phone_iso3166.country import *
>>> phone_country(45)
'DK'
>>> phone_country('+1 202-456-1111')
'US'
>>> phone_country(14412921234)
'BM'
```

Answer (score 2):

Small addition - you also can get country prefix by string code. E.g.:

```py
from phonenumbers.phonenumberutil import country_code_for_region

print(country_code_for_region('RU'))
print(country_code_for_region('DE'))
```